# Como detectar mudanças no DOM (Document Object Model)

Tags: javascript, dom

A cada mudança no **DOM** (Document Object Model), seja ela uma inclusão, exclusão ou até mesmo uma modificação em algum elemento eu gostaria de executar uma função, existe alguma maneira "simples" de fazer isso?

Caso não haja como detectar mudanças tão especificas, um método que detectasse qualquer alteração feita já é o suficiente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atualmente, a solução mais recomendável é a utilização de um [**Mutation Observer**](http://www.javascripture.com/MutationObserver)

*Gráfico de suporte completo por browsers pode ser conferido em [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)*

**O que é um Mutation Observer?**

É uma API que permite que uma função seja chamada de forma assíncrona quando houver mudança em certas partes do DOM.